# Reference to undefined variable jrebel_args

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, jrebel, eclipse-marketplace

Getting following error while trying to run Struts 2 app on server (Apache Tomcat 7, Eclipse - Kepler). Previously I installed jRebel from Eclipse marketplace and then uninstalled it.

How can I get rid of jRebel_args ?.

I searched for jrebel_args all over the Application, don't have any occurrence.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open up your Tomcat run configuration and in the VM arguments delete the `${jrebel_args}` bit.